# Ensuring reproducible builds using NuGet packages

Tags: .net, dependencies, nuget, versioning, binary-reproducibility

I have a .NET app called `Application`.

This application depends on two NuGet packages:

- `Database`, version 2.*
- `Logging`, version 3.*

The `Database` package depends on two additional packages:

- `DTO`, version 1.*
- `DAL`, version 4.*

Currently, `Application` uses these concrete package versions: `Database` version 2.1, `Logging` version 3.1.

I build my `Application`, NuGet resolves and downloads the dependencies, so I get `DTO` version 1.5 and `DAL` version 4.0. I put my `Application` into an installation package and deliver to my customer. I tag this release in git with `app-1.0`.

So my customer gets the following binaries:

- `Application.exe`, version 1.0
- `Database.dll`, version 2.1
- `Logging.dll`, version 3.1
- `DTO.dll`, version 1.5
- `DAL.dll`, version 4.0

One year later, the customer files a bug which I need to thoroughly analyse. To reproduce the issue, I need the same binaries as the customer, so I check out the tag `app-1.0` and want to build my application.

Meanwhile, the `DAL` and the `DTO` packages were updated on the NuGet feed: latest `DTO` version is 1.7 and `DAL` version is 4.5.

My questions are:

- When I build my application now, does NuGet resolve the `Database` dependencies to the latest available versions? So do I get `DTO 1.7` and `DAL 4.5` instead of `DTO 1.5` and `DAL 4.0` (which were used to build `app-1.0`)?
- If yes, how can I ensure the binary reproducibility of my release using NuGet?
- If no, how does NuGet manage to resolve the "right" references?

Comment: You are using a concrete nuget package with version specified in `packages.config` or in `PackageReference`. You can build your code tagged as `app-1.0` with old versions of packages (if you didn't update them, of course)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the question is not about the packages I **directly** reference. The question is about the floating **dependencies** of the packages I reference.

Comment: You are specified the minimal versions of dependent packages on nuget. The answer depends on `Database` package configuration. If it works with old versions of `DTO` and `DAL`, it won't be any issues with building the code. There is also no issues if build the code against `app-1.0` without updating a packages versions using `Update-Package` in nuget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NuGet introduced lock files in version 4.9 (Visual Studio 2017, 15.9), .NET Core SDK 2.1.500. [The blog post that introduces it is even titled "Enable repeatable package restores using a lock file"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/enable-repeatable-package-restores-using-a-lock-file/)

The blog post only lists one way to enable lock files. One way is to create an empty file named `packages.lock.json` in the same directory as your project file (`csproj`), then do a restore. Another way is to run `dotnet restore --use-lock-file` on the command line. Another way is to set the `RestorePackagesWithLockFile` MSBuild property to `true`, which is possible in many ways (property in your project file, property in `Directory.Build.props`, environment variable, command line argument).

Once the lock file is created, it will always be used, so you no longer need to explicitly opt-in as you need to the first time. Note that restore will update the lock file by default when it finds changes. If you want to fail restore when it can't restore the exact same packages, you need to opt-in to "locked mode", for example `dotnet restore --locked-mode`, which you probably want to do on your CI machines.